# Sleep a random time in with iMacros, works on FireFox/Chrome plugin

Tags: macros, imacros

I am automating tasks on a social network and I want to sleep random times in order to evade any macro detection.

How do I make the macro sleep a random time using Imacros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others looking to do this, use:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1); randomNumber;")
```

To set the random variable. The '**10**' represents the *upper limit* of the rand var.

Use this code to call the random wait time:

```
WAIT SECONDS={{!VAR1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

the proper calculation of MIN and MAX values for randomization can be done using below formula:

```
Math.random()*(Max-Min+1) + Min
```

so if you want random wait from 10 seconds to 60 seconds it will look like this

```
Math.random()*(60-10+1) + 10 = Math.random()*51 + 10
```