# Specific (not random) add time to imacros with each replay

Tags: batch-file, macros

In the following post [Sleep a random time in with iMacros, works on FireFox/Chrome plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017221/sleep-a-random-time-in-with-imacros-works-on-firefox-chrome-plugin/15019651)

it describes how to add RANDOM time to replays.

My question: Is there a way to add a SPECIFIC amount of time to each replay either via the macro file or batch file.... such as it plays the first time at say 6pm, then the second time it plays same time the next day PLUS 2 minutes (so 6:02pm) then the third day another 2 minutes added (6:04pm) ??

Im running the macro from a batch file, so I could put it in there if there is a way.... ?? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But for this you need JavaScript scripting and a use of Date() objest in JS. Also look at this.

[How do I get the current time only in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599148/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-only-in-javascript)